# How to sort list by what I want first, then by alphabetical order

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, lambda

These are the two lists and they co-relate to each other

```py
fruits = ['watermelon','orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'apple', 'grapes']
values = [3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```

And I would like to have 'grapes', 'orange', 'apple' to come first, and then the rest by alphabetic order.

Final list:

```py
new_fruits = ['grapes', 'orange', 'apple', 'mango', 'pear', 'watermelon' ]
new_values = [4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

How can I achieve this?

I used .sort() but this only helps to sort it by alphabetical order and not by what I want first.

Comment: Do you care about the order of `'grapes', 'orange', 'apple'`, or do you just want those three first in any order? What if there's multiple `'grapes'`, `'orange'`, or `'apple`'? Should all of those come first, or do you just need one of each and should the rest be sorted into their alphabetical place?

Comment: It will be difficult to sort those two lists independently, you're better off creating a list of tuples then splitting it afterwards if you need to.

Comment: This isn't really a sort - it's a rearrangement. There's no ordered relationship between the pairs of values

Comment: I disagree that the identified duplicate is really a duplicate, this question has additional complications.

Comment: Whoa, I forgot the dupe-hammer works both ways.

Answer (score 0):

To sort both lists together, you should combine them into a single list then split them apart afterwards.

```
combined = list(zip(fruits, values))
sorted_list = sorted(combined)
new_fruits = [item[0] for item in sorted_list]
new_values = [item[1] for item in sorted_list]
```

Now you just need to use the `key` argument to `sorted` to get the correct order.

```
d = {'grapes':0, 'orange':1, 'apple':2}
tail = max(d.values()) + 1
def key_func(item):
    return (d.get(item[0], tail), item[0])
sorted_list = sorted(combined, key=key_func)
```

The `key_func` returns a tuple consisting of an integer for ordering your priority items, followed by the first part of the input tuple which is the fruit name.  Python's sort will use a tuple key by ordering according to each element of the tuple in order, so first by priority code and then by name.

Comment: @sahasrara62 I was still working that out.  I saw some close votes on the question, so I wanted to post an answer before that happened.

Comment: Mark, you may use a simpler lambda: `sorted_list = sorted(combined, key=lambda item:d.get(item[0]) or item[0])`

Comment: The value returned by the key function can be a tuple. So you could map grapes, oranges and apples to a number and everything else to another number and return that number and the string itself. This would have the benefit of not depending on certain characters not occurring and it will make it obvious that there are two sort criterias.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that was a good suggestion that I have now implemented.  I actually thought of the same thing when I first wrote the answer, but as I stated earlier I was in a rush.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
>>> new_fruits = ['grapes', 'orange', 'apple', 'mango', 'pear', 'watermelon','apple' ]
>>> new_values = [4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6]
>>> l = list(zip(new_fruits, new_values))
>>> order = [ 'grapes', 'orange', 'apple']
>>> result = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0] not  in order))
>>> new_sorted_fruits = [i[0] for i in result]
>>> new_sorted_values = [i[1] for i in result]
>>> new_sorted_fruits
['grapes', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'mango', 'pear', 'watermelon']
>>> new_sorted_values
[4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: your lambda is incorrect, you don't sort the tail of the list that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mySorting(fruits, values, first_few_items):
    dct = {fruits[i]:values[i] for i in range(len(fruits))}
    new_fruits = [x for x in fruits if x not in first_few_items]
    new_fruits.sort()
    new_fruits = first_few_items + new_fruits
    new_values = [dct[x] for x in new_fruits]
    return(new_fruits, new_values)

fruits = ['watermelon','orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'apple', 'grapes']
values = [3,5,2,3,2,4]
first_few_items = ['grapes', 'orange', 'apple']
r = mySorting(fruits, values, first_few_items)
print(r)

#output:
(['grapes', 'orange', 'apple', 'mango', 'pear', 'watermelon'], [4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3])
```

In the above code, the first few items are not just limited to three. You can add as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
fruits = ['watermelon', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'apple', 'grapes']
values = [3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4]
firsts = ['grapes', 'orange', 'apple']
```

You can create a mapping dict `mapping` that maps fruit names to respective values, and another mapping `index` that maps fruit names in `firsts` to their respective indices for ordering:

```
mapping = dict(zip(fruits, values))
index = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(firsts)))
```

with which you can sort `fruits` with a key function that returns a tuple with the first item being the fruit's `index` value if it can be found, or infinity to make the fruit go in the latter group, and the second item being the fruit's name for alphabetical ordering. `new_values` would then be values in `new_fruits` mapped with `mapping`:

```
new_fruits = sorted(fruits, key=lambda k: (index.get(k, float('inf')), k))
new_values = list(map(mapping.get, new_fruits))
```

so that:

```
print(new_fruits)
print(new_values)
```

outputs:

```
['grapes', 'orange', 'apple', 'mango', 'pear', 'watermelon']
[4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/oxeCRu

Comment: This won't work in case there are any duplicates (it will silently discard them).

Comment: Updated for that possiblity then.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the most efficient solution but shows a step-wise approach for clarity.

```
fruits = ["watermelon", "orange", "pear", "mango", "apple", "grapes"]
values = [3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4]

# create a sorted list of tuples (fruit/value) pairs
# natural sort
temp = sorted(zip(fruits, values))

# note how the fruit names are in reverse order
for fruit in "apple", "orange", "grapes":
    for i, (f, v) in enumerate(temp.copy()):
        if f == fruit:
            del temp[i]
            temp.insert(0, (f, v))
            break

new_fruits = [f for f, _ in temp]
new_values = [v for _, v in temp]

print(new_fruits)
print(new_values)
```

**Output:**

```
['grapes', 'orange', 'apple', 'mango', 'pear', 'watermelon']
[4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a single sort.

Notice that `'682190'<'a'` (numbers as strings are *smaller* than alphabetic characters).

```
# [added some more fruits]
fruits = ['zfruit', 'ananas', 'watermelon','orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'apple', 'banana', 'grapes']
values = [0,0,3,5,2,3,2,0,4]

# exception of the order
first_fruits = 'grapes', 'orange', 'apple'

new_fruits, new_values = \
    zip(*sorted(zip(fruits, values),
                key=lambda x: (
                    str(first_fruits.index(x[0]))
                    if x[0] in first_fruits
                    else x[0]
                    )
    ))
print(new_fruits)
#('grapes', 'orange', 'apple', 'ananas', 'banana', 'mango', 'pear', 'watermelon', 'zfruit')
print(new_values)
#(4, 5, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0)
```

---

Using built-in functions. Notice that

1. a dictionary can be generated from a list of tuple of the form `(key, value)`
2. a list of tuple of the form `(key, value)` can be generated by `zip`ping to lists, one for the keys and one for the values. With a further application of 1. you can a `dict` from them
3. chain dictionaries with some common keys keeps the order of insertion

```
fruits = ['watermelon','orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'apple', 'grapes']
values = [3,5,2,3,2,4]

# exception of the order
first_fruits = 'grapes', 'orange', 'apple'

# initial order for exceptions
tmp_sorted = dict.fromkeys(first_fruits)

# sort all data alphabetically & add sorted fruits
tmp_sorted.update(sorted(zip(fruits, values)))

# decouple keys and values
new_fruits, new_values = zip(*tmp_sorted.items())
print(new_fruits, new_values)
```